# Can OAuth2 redirect URI expose authorization code to a client-side app?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Let's say we have a client SPA, and an API for our application:

- myapp.com
- api.myapp.com

Using OAuth2 authorization code flow, we need to specify a `redirect_uri`. I thought it was best practice to never expose the `access_token` or `authorization_code` to the front end.

I see many examples where it is suggested to register a redirect uri pointing to the client app for SPAs and native mobile apps. For example:
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/

Should you register the redirect uri as `myapp.com/callback` or `api.myapp.com/callback`? What are the pros/cons to each approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply configure your Backend API endpoint as your redirect URI.

The reason being is that you have to trade the authorization code for an access token using the token endpoint which would make sense if you do it in the backend server, especially when your OAuth client is a confidential client (client configured with a secret)

Exchanging authorization code with a token in the UI for a confidential OAuth client would expose the client's secret in the front-end which I would not recommend

If your OAuth client is a public one and if you have a SPA but you don't own a server or backend APIs, then you can configure your SPA URL as the redirect URI. In this case, I would suggest you go with the 'Authorization Code with PKCE' flow which expects you to provide a code challenge and code verifier.

But in your case, since you already own a backend server, I would recommend you to go with the Backend API as the redirect URI